# Scale and Centre image - Skimage

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am trying to scale a set of images in Skimage. I am using the following code, which works well, except that the new rescaled image (by a factor 2) is now centered in the top-left (see below). I would like the image to remain in the original centre. Is there a simple way to achieve this? My aim is to have the saved copy of the image (e.g. as jpg file) to remain centered. My question does not concern the display of the image through imshow. E.g. when i save the image per below - the image is centered to the upper left, which causes issues with subsequent steps in my code.

```
    ###Part of the code
    tform=skimage.transform.SimilarityTransform(scale=2, rotation=0,translation=(0, 0))
    rotated = skimage.transform.warp(test, tform)  
    plt.imshow(rotated)
    import scipy
    scipy.misc.imsave('rotated.jpg', rotated)
```

[image]

Comment: I clarifed the question - which i think is different from the earlier question that related to plotting

Answer (score 0):

Scaling as itself is defined as one subset of affine transformations. 
The affine transformation matrix for scaling only is defined as

```
s_x, 0,   0
0,   s_y, 0
0,   0,   1
```

where `s_x` and `s_y` are the scaling factors in the respective dimensions (defined relative to the origin at `(0,0)`). If you want your image, to be scaled not relative to the origin, but another point, you first translate the image , so that the center of scaling is in the origin, then you scale, then you move the image back. You simply do a matrix multiplication of your transform matrices with the scale matrix. I had a similar problem with rotation, that can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093314/rotation-matrix-and-of-rotation-around-a-point). Same principle applies for this problem. The result is

```
s_x,  0, (-s_x*x)+x
0,  s_y, (-s_y*y)+y
0,    0,          1
```

where `x` and `y` are half the size of your image in the respective dimensions.
The resulting matrix can be used with:

```
skimage.transform.AffineTransform(matrix)
```